# Making monster mobs more interesting in creative mode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have Minecraft, and tend to play in survival mode.

My children like creative mode. As well as buildings and rollercoasters, they have started to be interested in creatures, and recently switched monsters on, treating them as "pets". I have helped them create "monster zoos" using spawn blocks etc.

The monster behaviour in creative mode is somewhat boring though. The children don't really want to fight the monsters, but might be entertained if they fought each other, or acted with some simple purpose. Even sheep tending to climb up are more entertaining than zombies on creative mode.

Are there ways to get a more interesting or entertaining behaviours out of the Minecraft monsters, when in creative mode?

---

Examples of things mobs do or have done that my children have found interesting:

- Witches taking potions when hurt
- Monsters getting into minecarts and riding rollercoasters
- Iron golems protecting villagers, and giving them flowers
- A "baby crowding waterfall" that happened to a mooshroom where they made it spawn around 100 babies, which then pushed it around (and mostly downhill) as the ones at the back tried to get closer.

Comment: Zombies like to "play" with villagers... I believe Wolf-Sheep and Ocelot-Creeper have interactions as well. Other than that, without mods(although I can't remember which... *mo' creatures* maybe?) I don't think there is much interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The monster behavior is **always** going to be less entertaining in creative mode. Due to the players being in creative, monsters will not target the player. Leading to less interesting behaviors. If your kids want monster behaviors to be more interesting, I would suggest a few things here.

- Spawn villagers in the vicinity of zombies, the zombies will target the villagers.
- Creepers will run away from cats/ocelots. Not sure it the cats will hurt the creepers though.
- Endermen don't like the water, it kills them. Obviously.
- Spiders climb up walls, but I don't know if they do that when provoked.

  - Your kids could build a "playpen" for the spiders to see if they **do** crawl up walls in creative.
- As for nether monsters, hitting a zombie pigman will provoke it, although, I don't know if this is the case in survival mode.

If you could be specific about what types of monsters your kids have in their "monster zoos" I could provide a few more suggestions. Anyways, I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I agree that all the existing AI used to hunt down and fight the player is unused in Creative. My kids would happily play with any of the monsters. Zoo currently includes cave spiders, skeletons, witches, blazes - but actually what they seem to be interested in is "what do they do?", there are no favourite monsters. A monster which interacted with environment or other monsters in a watchable way would *become* a favourite. Example: Witches are slightly more interesting for my kids because if they get hurt, they take a potion, and you can see that happening.

Comment: Marking this as accepted as my daughter is currently entertaining herself with a "zombie maze" spawning villagers inside it, and with an Iron Golem in the centre area to give the villagers some protection. The question remains closed unfortunately despite my edit to meet site rules.